Idiomatic way to transform a value by applying a list of functions in Elm
Given a list of functions that transform a value, what is the most idiomatic way to apply them? Example:
let
    transformations = [ String.replace "dogs" "cats"
                      , String.replace "bark" "purr"
                      ]
    str = "dogs are the best, they bark"
in
    foldl (\t acc -> t acc) str transformations

I don't like the (\t acc -> t acc) which seems redundant. But I couldn't come up with another way of writing the last line.
Of course in this simple example I could pull out the String.replace into a function transform (s, r) = String.replace s r. But in my use case the functions are arbitrary. Also I think I can learn something about the language that way :-)

The way you did it is idiomatic as the lambda is clear and Elm encourages clarity.
You could have used List.foldl (<|) str transformations instead of the lambda but that is more cryptic for people that are not used to the reverse pipe being used as a function.
One other way to do it is:

applyAll : List (a -> a) -> a -> a 
applyAll funcs start = 
     List.foldl (<|) start funcs


let
    transformations = [ String.replace "dogs" "cats"
                      , String.replace "bark" "purr"
                      ]
    str = "dogs are the best, they bark"
in
    applyAll transformations str



Thanks for the response. I agree the (<|) is rather cryptic. Putting it in a named function would give readers like me the chance to understand what is going on. So if I'd have repeated use for this it would be a nice option.
